# Find the critical point and show it is not a global minimizer (using Hessian)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

> Consider the function $f(x,y) = x^3 + e^{3y}-3xe^y$. Show that $f$ has exactly one critical point and that this point is a local minimizer, but not a global minimizer.

I have attempted this, but it seems that I have made a mistake somewhere along the way. Can someone please help me find where I went wrong?

**My attempt:**

\begin{align}\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}3x^2 -3e^y \\3e^{3y} -3xe^y\end{bmatrix} = \bar{0}\end{align}
Thus giving the following two homogeneous equations
\begin{align}3x^2 - 3e^y &= 0\\ 3e^{3y} - 3xe^y &=0\end{align}

From the second equation we find that $$x = e^{2y}$$ and upon substitution into the first equation we find that $$e^y(e^{3y} -1) =0$$

Notice however that $e^y \neq 0$ and we must that have that $e^{3y}=1 \implies y=0$ and thus $x =1$

Our critical point is thus $(x,y) = (1,0)$.

How consider the Hessian

\begin{align}H_f &= \begin{bmatrix}6x & -3e^y \\ -3e^y & 9e^{3y}-3xe^y\end{bmatrix}\end{align}
Evaluated at our critical point we obtain $$H = \begin{bmatrix}6 & -3 \\ -3& 6\end{bmatrix}$$

We can then deduce that $H_f$ is positive definite and thus our critical point must be a strict global minimizer. This, however is the exact opposite of what the question stated?

**Edit:**
This is the theorem in my notes that I tried to use:

[image]

Comment: You have shown that you have a local minimum.  (Now you want to show that it is not a global minimum, by showing the function has smaller values.)

Comment: @Thomas - How come? Did I not use everything as in the theorem? (Critical point, Hessian at that point and the found the Hessian and the point is positive definite)?

Comment: The theorem you cited assumes something about the Hessian in every $x$. You only have the definiteness in one point (or did I miss something)

Comment: @Thomas - I see what you mean now! :). Thank you! :). The Hessian is not positive definite over the whole of $\mathbb R^2$ and hence the minimizer is only local and not global :)

Comment: It may be. This requires additional reasoning

Comment: (The really remarkable fact about the function which is discussed here is that it has a unique strict local minumum and therefore satisfies most prerequisites of the mountain pass theorem, while it does not satisfy the conclusion that theorem. This means it cannot be proper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong. If the Hessian is positive definite, the critical point is a *local* minimizer.

Comment: I think I see now.! :).  The Hessian is not positive definite over the WHOLE of $\mathbb R^2$ (as would be required in the Theorem) and hence the minimizer is only local and not global :). Is this correct?